# AWS SageMaker Upload File but Download of Same File gets a 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I am seeing a radical change in behavior from my AWS SageMaker account behavior today. I don't see any service warnings on the site but unfortunately I am in the trial period and can not get technical support.

So, I setup a simple test to see if someone has seen this and TIA for any suggestions on what I might try:

1. I can upload a file to my juypter notebook home directory.  Upload is successful.  File appears in the directory.
2. When I try to download the same file I just uploaded, I get the following error:403 : Forbidden
   The error was: Blocking Cross Origin request from https://alpha-gold.notebook.us-east-1.sagemaker.aws/tree/
3. I can rename the file in the home directory.
4. I can run notebooks in the home directory.
5. I can down juypter notebooks as either notebooks are else as .html via the notebook menu options.
6. I CANNOT download a py file or png file - 403 error
7. I can load the py file into my notebook and it does works correctly.

I hope this is a transient condition. However, on the off chance this is something that is fixable, TIA.

Comment: This does not look like a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Jupyter notebook. alternatively, you can open jupyterlab and then you should be able to download the files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using SageMaker.

This issue was related to Jupyter, which has been addressed and should not be occurring as of now.

Here is the GitHub issue for this problem: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5067

Answer (score 0):

I am from SageMaker Notebooks team.

It was an issue on our end, we pushed a bad change. The change has been reverted. Please let us know if you are still seeing this issue.

Thanks,

Neelam